# wget+ftp: How to download remote directory without remote tree

Tags: ftp, wget, local

I'm trying to download a single directory from a remote ftp server. I'm using this command

```
wget -nH -r -N -l inf --ask-password ftp://ftp.server.com/some/remote/dir/xyz -P dirName
```

I'd like the remote `xyz` directory to be copied and called `dirName`. There is a local directory called `dirName`, but its contents are `dirName/some/remote/dir/xyz`, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

After a careful reading of the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options) I found the `--cut-dirs` option which cuts parent directories from the local storage. That does what I need it to do!